# Manually invoke actionPerformed of a javax.swing.Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

The following Timer works perfectly.

```
private static final Timer TICK_HOUR = new Timer(3600000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

What I want to do is call the `actionPerformed()` manually. How can I achieve this?

---

The question seems unclear to the readers, I'll try to explain more.

Timer does some process hourly. I want to do it whenever I want without interfering the timer's process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer...

A much simpler (and better designed) solution would be, instead of...

```
private static final Timer TICK_HOUR = new Timer(3600000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
});
```

You should externalise the work the `ActionListener` does...

```
private static final Timer TICK_HOUR = new Timer(3600000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doReallyImportantWorkEveryHour();
    }
});
```

then you remove the `Timer` from the equation and you can call `doReallyImportantWorkEveryHour` when you want and solve the fundamental problem

## Long Answer

So, let's start with...

```
private static final Timer TICK_HOUR = new Timer(3600000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
});
```

Creating a `Timer` this way, automatically registers a `ActionListener` with the `Timer`.

You then state:

> What I want to do is call the actionPerformed() method inside the timer's ActionListener manually. How can I achieve this?

Which suggest you want try and do something like...

```
private static final Timer TICK_HOUR = new Timer(3600000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TICK_HOUR.getActionListeners()[0].actionPerformed(null);
    }
});
```

This could cause a `NullPointerException`, but more importantly, this will have an adverse affect on system performance, as there is no way that the `ActionListener` will know it shouldn't continuously all itself - basically and infinite loop.

## IF however, you wanted to, prematurely, trigger the `Timer`s `ActionListener`s (outside of any registered listeners)

Then yes, you could use...

```
ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(
                TICK_HOUR, 
                0, 
                TICK_HOUR.getActionCommand(), 
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                0);
for (ActionListener listener : TICK_HOUR.getActionListeners()) {
    listener.actionPerformed(evt);
}
```

but make sure you're calling them from within the context of the EDT, as that's one of the guarantees that the `Timer` makes.

A "simpler" solution might be just to use the functionality that is already provide by the `Timer` itself...

```
public class ManuallyTimer extends Timer {

    public ManuallyTimer(int delay, ActionListener listener) {
        super(delay, listener);
    }

    public void tigger() {
        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(TICK_HOUR, 0, TICK_HOUR.getActionCommand());
        fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 0, getActionCommand(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        0));
    }
}
```

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Before you edited it, to correct it, this is EXACTLY what you said you wanted - however, I have gone through a number of scenarios - see the section titled *"IF however, you wanted to, prematurely, trigger the Timers ActionListeners (outside of any registered listeners)"*

Comment: Very good answer. I like the part of delegating the work to another method. Which splits up the logic of doing work every hour and *actually* doing the work itself. Which IMO should always be done for clearance and clean code.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a `static-initializer`-block store `ActionListener` in a variable instead of passing it directly to the `Timer`:

```
private static final Timer TICK_HOUR;

static{
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // ...
        }
    };

    TICK_HOUR =  = new Timer(3600000, listener);

    listener.actionPerformed(/* someEvent */);
}
```

You might aswell store the `listener` variable as a class level static variable and then call it elsewhere from your code:

```
private static final ActionListener LISTENER = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // ...
    }
};

private static final Timer TICK_HOUR = new Timer(3600000, LISTENER);
```

And then somewhere in your code

```
LISTENER.actionPerformed(/* someEvent */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`getActionListeners()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#getActionListeners--).

> Returns an array of all the action listeners registered on this timer.
>   Returns:
>   **all of the timer's ActionListeners or an empty array if no action listeners are currently registered.**
>   [~Java doc~](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#getActionListeners--)

```
TICK_HOUR.getActionListeners()[0].actionPerformed(null);
```

This will throw a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there are no `ActionListener`s registered to the timer. So better check the length of the array before using.

Comment: if you like answering questions the same time you asked it, try blogging instead :)

Comment: @gagansingh actually there was no question about this matter while I was searching. And SO is the best place where another developer can easily find this other than a blog. That's why I prefer to use SO to spread knowledge. :)

Comment: You’re going to trigger a StackOverFlow report doing this. In order to call the ActionListener from inside the actionPerformed , then you already have an at least one ActionListener registered - which brings back the first part of the comment

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I mean your answer will cause one

Comment: @MadProgrammer No. I have tested it, in fact I'm using it now in one of my applications

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala *"What I want to do is call the actionPerformed() method inside the timer's ActionListener manually"* - This says you want to call the `Timer`'s `ActionListener`s from within a `ActionListener` from already registered with a `Timer` - while, yes, I jumped the gun and it won't cause a SOE, it will basically, continuously call itself, which could have an adverse affect on the systems performance (sorry, reading on my mobile)

Comment: Oh.. I think you have misunderstood the question. I don't want to call the method within the action listener method. I have edited the question

Comment: BUT that's EXACTLY what the question says *""What I want to do is call the actionPerformed() method **inside the timer's ActionListener** manually""*